# Cannot log in to the MySQL server with error (HY000/2002) after upgrading to20.04

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to log in it says Cannot log in to the MySQL with the error (HY000/2002)
[image]

After I upgraded my server from 18.04 to 20.04 I can't log in anymore  so anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

If phpMyAdmin is running on the same server as the database, you'll want to update your `config.inc.php` file, replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`. The result should look something like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

By default, phpMyAdmin will try to connect to the `mysql.socket` connection when you use `localhost`. When you use `127.0.0.1` it will make a TCP connection, which should resolve the issue.

Comment: it added Server Choice but same proplem and btw the server have static ip

Comment: Regardless of whether the server has a static or dynamic IP address, `127.0.0.1` *always* points to the host (unless you've specifically modified this for some reason). If you are still unable to connect, then there is an `error` log in your `/var/log/apache2` directory that should contain more specific information.

Comment: Sorry for taking long  but the /var/log/apache2 is empty and says new buffer

Comment: in the error log there is somthing with  /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock with port 3306  and blind address if this may help